# Add custom manifest entry to JavaFX application in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, manifest, splash-screen

I want to show a splash screen for my JavaFX application.
For this, I want to specify a corresponding entry in the manifest file.

```
SplashScreen-Image: images/splash.gif
```

So java handles the display for me.
I didn´t find a way to add this custom entry to the manifest file in IntelliJ (2016.3.7)

I want to avoid using ANT or Maven.
How can I do this?

Comment: F4 -> Artefacts -> Java FX -> Custom Manifest Atributes ?

Comment: Thanks! I just didn´t see it :-)

Answer (score 0):

The answer from mr mcwolf works. In the project settings I can add custom manifest properties.

I figured out, that there is a bug in IntelliJ (at least my version 2016.3.7) which has the effect, that scrolling isn´t possible and no scroll bars are shown. So, the option for adding manifest properties is not visible.

[image: project settings dialog]

But when resizing the dialog, the additional options appear!

[image: resized dialog]

This is why I didn´t see it.